# Selenium: How to delete single characters from a textbox?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

> Using Selenium how to delete single characters from a textbox using Selenium?

I have to delete the last 2 characters from text box.

Ex: ABCD to AB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Java, try this to delete one character:

```
element.sendKeys("\u0008");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what this "\u0008" is? ASCII value of backspace is 0x08

Comment: "\u0008" is Unicode for the backspace character.  The sendKeys method takes a CharacterSequence as input.  "\u0008" is a CharacterSequence; 0x08 is an integer instead of a CharacterSequence.  Moreover, you cannot use 0x notation to encode characters within a Java string.

Answer (score 13):

While using the ASCII valid (\u008) is valid, there are already defines for this which makes your code more readable, as such:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
```

For a list of the key names, there's some [official documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html).